# How can I iterate through the property names of the prototype of an html element?

Tags: javascript

For example, I can iterate through the properties in Element.prototype by using

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Element.prototype).forEach(/*does the thing*/)
```

but I can't seem to find a way to iterate through the properties of an element like "audio".  Trying to iterate over HTMLAudioElement for example just yields an array with ["constructor"] when it definitely has more properties than that.  Does anyone know how to do this?

More background:
   I'm trying to build a proxy class that hands values to an element but triggers an event.  The class needs to have the same properties as the element it's acting as a proxy for.

Comment: Despite no real resolution to the question (thanks to everyone that gave it a shot), I've compiled a map of tags and properties.  Initially, this was > 230k, but I managed to write a simple compression to push it down to about 9k.  If anyone's interested in the decompressor or the tag/property map I posted it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hedzer/55e08rew/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTMLAudioElement has no specific properties as it inherits its properties from its parent, HTMLMediaElement, and from HTMLElement.

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(HTMLMediaElement)`

outputs:

```
["length", "name", "arguments", "caller", "prototype", "NETWORK_EMPTY",
 "NETWORK_IDLE", "NETWORK_LOADING", "NETWORK_NO_SOURCE", 
 "HAVE_NOTHING", "HAVE_METADATA", "HAVE_CURRENT_DATA", 
 "HAVE_FUTURE_DATA", "HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA", "toString"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

As @self pointed out in the comments below, you could also use:

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(HTMLAudioElement.__proto__)`

to get the same result, without having to know which class HTMLAudioElement inherits from.

Comment: You can do `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(HTMLMediaElement.__proto__)` To get it's parent without knowing it.

Comment: Still, some properties don't show up, like "volume" or "autoPlay" or "canPlayType".  It's the sort of meat of what I'm looking for; the properties people would normally access that are unique to the element.  After a lot of testing, I can't seem to find anything that works,  If no one else has figured it out soon I'll mark this answer as correct (it would be about as correct as it can get).  Thanks a bunch.  NodeWebkit allowed me to enumerate the properties, so I might just build a map.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox I was able to get all properties of the audio element with for in.

```
for (let prop in Audio.prototype) {
    console.log(prop);
}
```

I used this to build an array I could then use in Chrome and Firefox.

```
const audioProps = ["load", "canPlayType", "fastSeek", "play", "pause", "addTextTrack", "mozCaptureStream", "mozCaptureStreamUntilEnded", "mozGetMetadata", "setMediaKeys", "seekToNextFrame", "error", "src", "currentSrc", "crossOrigin", "networkState", "preload", "buffered", "readyState", "seeking", "currentTime", "duration", "paused", "defaultPlaybackRate", "playbackRate", "played", "seekable", "ended", "autoplay", "loop", "controls", "volume", "muted", "defaultMuted", "textTracks", "srcObject", "mozPreservesPitch", "mozAudioCaptured", "mozFragmentEnd", "mediaKeys", "onencrypted", "onwaitingforkey", "NETWORK_EMPTY", "NETWORK_IDLE", "NETWORK_LOADING", "NETWORK_NO_SOURCE", "HAVE_NOTHING", "HAVE_METADATA", "HAVE_CURRENT_DATA", "HAVE_FUTURE_DATA", "HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA", "click", "focus", "blur", "title", "lang", "dir", "innerText", "hidden", "accessKey", "accessKeyLabel", "draggable", "contentEditable", "isContentEditable", "spellcheck", "nonce", "offsetParent", "offsetTop", "offsetLeft", "offsetWidth", "offsetHeight", "oncopy", "oncut", "onpaste", "style", "onabort", "onblur", "onfocus", "onauxclick", "onbeforeinput", "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onchange", "onclick", "onclose", "oncontextmenu", "oncuechange", "ondblclick", "ondrag", "ondragend", "ondragenter", "ondragexit", "ondragleave", "ondragover", "ondragstart", "ondrop", "ondurationchange", "onemptied", "onended", "onformdata", "oninput", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onload", "onloadeddata", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadend", "onloadstart", "onmousedown", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onwheel", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onratechange", "onreset", "onresize", "onscroll", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onstalled", "onsubmit", "onsuspend", "ontimeupdate", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onselectstart", "ontoggle", "onpointercancel", "onpointerdown", "onpointerup", "onpointermove", "onpointerout", "onpointerover", "onpointerenter", "onpointerleave", "ongotpointercapture", "onlostpointercapture", "onmozfullscreenchange", "onmozfullscreenerror", "onanimationcancel", "onanimationend", "onanimationiteration", "onanimationstart", "ontransitioncancel", "ontransitionend", "ontransitionrun", "ontransitionstart", "onwebkitanimationend", "onwebkitanimationiteration", "onwebkitanimationstart", "onwebkittransitionend", "dataset", "tabIndex", "onerror", "getAttributeNames", "getAttribute", "getAttributeNS", "toggleAttribute", "setAttribute", "setAttributeNS", "removeAttribute", "removeAttributeNS", "hasAttribute", "hasAttributeNS", "hasAttributes", "closest", "matches", "webkitMatchesSelector", "getElementsByTagName", "getElementsByTagNameNS", "getElementsByClassName", "insertAdjacentElement", "insertAdjacentText", "mozMatchesSelector", "setPointerCapture", "releasePointerCapture", "hasPointerCapture", "setCapture", "releaseCapture", "getAttributeNode", "setAttributeNode", "removeAttributeNode", "getAttributeNodeNS", "setAttributeNodeNS", "getClientRects", "getBoundingClientRect", "scrollIntoView", "scroll", "scrollTo", "scrollBy", "insertAdjacentHTML", "querySelector", "querySelectorAll", "attachShadow", "requestFullscreen", "mozRequestFullScreen", "requestPointerLock", "animate", "getAnimations", "before", "after", "replaceWith", "remove", "prepend", "append", "replaceChildren", "namespaceURI", "prefix", "localName", "tagName", "id", "className", "classList", "part", "attributes", "scrollTop", "scrollLeft", "scrollWidth", "scrollHeight", "clientTop", "clientLeft", "clientWidth", "clientHeight", "scrollTopMax", "scrollLeftMax", "innerHTML", "outerHTML", "shadowRoot", "assignedSlot", "slot", "onfullscreenchange", "onfullscreenerror", "previousElementSibling", "nextElementSibling", "children", "firstElementChild", "lastElementChild", "childElementCount", "getRootNode", "hasChildNodes", "insertBefore", "appendChild", "replaceChild", "removeChild", "normalize", "cloneNode", "isSameNode", "isEqualNode", "compareDocumentPosition", "contains", "lookupPrefix", "lookupNamespaceURI", "isDefaultNamespace", "nodeType", "nodeName", "baseURI", "isConnected", "ownerDocument", "parentNode", "parentElement", "childNodes", "firstChild", "lastChild", "previousSibling", "nextSibling", "nodeValue", "textContent", "ELEMENT_NODE", "ATTRIBUTE_NODE", "TEXT_NODE", "CDATA_SECTION_NODE", "ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE", "ENTITY_NODE", "PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE", "COMMENT_NODE", "DOCUMENT_NODE", "DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE", "DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE", "NOTATION_NODE", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY", "DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC", "addEventListener", "removeEventListener", "dispatchEvent"];
```